# Checking to see if a checkbox is selected jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a list of tv stations that have checkboxes, I am trying to write a jquery function to check if the checkbox is checked but what I am doing is coming up empty, so I am unsure how to check if the box is checked.  The html and function is below.

```
<div class="offline-data">
  <div class="stations-container">
    <% TelevisionStation.each do |station| %>
      <div class="offline-station" id="television-stations">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="<%= station.id%>"> <%= station.name%> (<%= station.affiliate%>)</input>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Function to check is the box is checked, this happens on a click event.

```
$('#television-stations').find('input:checked').each(function () {
  television_stations.push($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an array of checkboxes within a div (id=television-stations) you can get the list of checked ones by

```
var boxes = $('div#television-stations input[type=checkbox]');
```

or

```
var boxes = $("#television-stations").children("input:checked");
```

then to loop through them and see what's checked you can do

```
var television_stations = [];
$(boxes).each(function(){
    television_stations.push($(this).val());
});
```

to find how many are checked you can do

```
$(boxes).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are using the .find method properly. How about adding a class to all of your station checkboxes called station:

```
<input type="checkbox" class='station' ... >
```

And then changing your jquery to this:

```
$('#television-stations').find('.station').each(function () {
television_stations.push($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

After reading Alek's comment I believe he is right. Where is the ID=television stations? A better jquery line would be:

```
$('.station').each(function () {
television_stations.push($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Comment: $('#television-stations .station').each(function () {
television_stations.push($(this).attr('value'));
});